# Do I need to setup separate User Profile Sync for each child domain?

Tags: user-profile-service, profile-sync

Our SharePoint 2013 on-premise farm is installed on our company major domain "Domain.com". We have setup user profile sync for domain.com. Under Domain.com there are several child domains a.com, b.com & c.com. These 3 domains have two-way trust with domain.com. On SharePoint users can locate a.com, b.com & c.com in people picker. However these 3 domain's user profile are not sync. Their "Display Name", "Email" and other attributes are not in User Profile database.

My question is, do I need to setup 3 additional UPS connection to these 3 domains? Or I should modify the existing connection (the connection for Domain.com)? Thanks.

---

Follow up question:
At the sync connection setup page, I have checked all domains as following picture:
[image]

If I click open the DOMAIN node > Users, I can see all users. If I click open A node > users. There is no user. Also, after I trigger a full sync, no user profiles from A & B domain are created.

In WFE server's DOS prompt I ran follow and get error:

> C:>nltest.exe /dsgetdc:A Getting DC name failed: Status = 1355 0x54b
>   ERROR_NO_SUCH_DOMAIN

I have verified with the domain controller admin A & B do have users. What could be the problem? Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you should be using the single sync connection for the entire forest. If you have a secondary forest (or more) create a sync connection per forest.

Comment: I am not familiar with AD concept. How can I verify a.com is same forest with domain.com?

Comment: Use nltest.exe /dsgetdc:A. It will tell you the domain and what forest it belongs to. Or use the Active Directory Domains and Trusts MMC, which will show you the domains of the current forest, and any trusts in place.

Comment: I typed the command at the SharePoint WFE. It return: Getting DC name failed: Status = 1355 0x54b ERROR_NO_SUCH_DOMAIN. Is it means the sub domain have configuration problem? (of coz I am typing in the real domain name)

Comment: Or the name you're using is simply incorrect. Using Active Directory Domains and Trusts, do you see the domain? Or if you click properties on the domain that SharePoint resides in and go to the Trusts tab, is it listed as a trusted forest?

Comment: Recently we setup a test subdomain named "Subdomain.com". It is under "Domain.com" (under same forest and verified with nltest.exe). There is one user subdomain\test01.

Comment: I can add it in people picker. Howver after a few trial of full sync its user profile still not be built.

Comment: Check for the sync accounts Replicate Directory rights within the subdomain. This is set up on a per-domain basis.

Comment: Sorry for bring up old topic. I forgot to ask whether any down side to setup connection for EACH domain? It is because our company's domain are managed by different companies. It is easier to ask them create a domain user under their domain. It is difficult to create single user have permission on entire forest.

Comment: Its not supported. The scope needs to be at the forest level.

Comment: Sorry one more question. In one forest contains 3 domains, how many cn=configuration containers I need to grant permission? Only ONE container or 3 containers?